# Position and Text of DIV Elements

Tags: html, css

I have a question concerning DIV elements. Please have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

The red DIV-boxes have the same css-class. Sometimes another DIV "B" is being added between them and the DIV "A". In this case the red DIV should be shorter and the text should be shortened as well (text-overflow: ellipsis).

Could you please tell me how I can tell the red DIV-boxes to get the right width with CSS?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="left">
    <div class="group">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="group">Hello again!</div>
</div>
<div class="middle-left">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>A</div>
</div>
```

CSS for group:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap !important;
width: ???????;
```

Comment: post what you've done so far. so is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Look up how position:relative, and float:left and float:right work.  Those 3 things are all you need.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: Please append the CSS currently used by the DIV elements that you want to adjust.

Comment: Hi, i just tried to add my code. Sorry - I'm a total rookie in this topic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.a, .b, .red {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.a, .b {
  width: 80px;
  display: flex; /* Magic again */
  align-items: center; /* Center content vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* Center content horizontally */
}
.red-wrapper {
  flex: 1; /* Occupy available space */
  min-width: 0; /* Ignore content */
}
.red {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent line breaks */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Show text ellipsis */
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red-wrapper">
    <div class="red">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="red">Hello again!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red-wrapper">
    <div class="red">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="red">Hello again!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to do it.

```
.a{
position:relative;
float:left;
height:40px;
width:40px;
border:1px solid;
}
.b{
position:relative;
float:left;
height:40px;
width:40px;
border:1px solid;
}
.c{
position:relative;
float:left;
height:80px;
width:40px;
border:1px solid;
}
.d{
position:relative;
float:left;
height:80px;
width:40px;
border:1px solid;
}

<div style="width:200px">
   <div  style="width:40px;float:left">
     <div class="a">
     Hello a
     </div>
     <div class="b">
     Hello b
     </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:130px">
    <div class="c">
    Hello c
    </div>
    <div class="d">
    Hello d
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```